# Execute concurrent processes using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I would like to setup a new PowerShell script that invokes my Database Stored Procedure concurrently. I am currently having a Control table that has a Job_ID column and a Code column. There might be more than one Job_ID for a code value in the Control table. Based on the code value I pass in the PowerShell along with a date, I would like the PowerShell to trigger the Stored Procedure which is expecting "Job_ID" and "MyDate" as input parameters.

FYI, I am using PowerShell and SQL Server 2016.

```
PS C:\PowerShell> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
2      0      -1     -1
```

Here is some sample data for your reference:

```
CREATE TABLE control_table(JOB_ID INT, CODE VARCHAR(5));
INSERT INTO control_table(1, 'ABC');
INSERT INTO control_table(2, 'ABC');
INSERT INTO control_table(3, 'ABC');
INSERT INTO control_table(1, 'DEF');
INSERT INTO control_table(1, 'GHI');

CREATE PROCEDURE myschema.run_job (@JOB_ID INT, @MyDate DATE)
AS
BEGIN
-- Do Something
END
```

When I run the PowerShell script by passing 'ABC" as code, it should execute all the three jobs concurrently by reading the control table.

Something like

```
.\test.ps1 –MyCode “ABC” –Dt “12/27/2018”
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: This post doesn't contain a single `?` - what is the question? :)

Comment: Look up [Start-Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-6).

Comment: I apologize. I am a newbie to PowerShell and doesn't have any initial code to show. I am trying to learn if it is possible to achieve the above and accordingly some help with building it.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to jobs you can use async methods of built-in SQL client. Below is the sample code. I assume you already has some "run_job" procedure that can execute other procedures (jobs) by id.

```
$code = "ABC"

$date = "2018-12-31"

$jobs = @{} # this  will store results of async jobs

$str = "Server = YourServer; Database = YourDB; Integrated Security = True;"

#-------- 

function Async-Sql { param($connStr, $sql, [switch]$GetDataTable)

 $conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $str
 $cmd = $conn.CreateCommand()
 $conn.Open()
 $cmd.CommandText = $sql

 if($GetDataTable) { 
   $dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable "result"
   $r = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
   $dt.Load($r)
   $conn.Close()
   return @(,$dt)

  } else {

   $w = $cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync()
   return [PSCustomObject]@{result=$w; conn = $conn} }
}


# ---------------------------------------------

# get a list of jobs from your control table, this will run synchronously
$jobList = Async-Sql -connStr $str -sql "select job_id, code from test.control_table where code = '$code'" -GetDataTable

# main loop. You should call your stored procedure here. Each iteration will create a new connection and execute command asynchronously
foreach($id in $jobList.job_id) {

  $command = "EXEC run_job $id, $date"
  $r = Async-Sql -connStr $str -sql $command
  $jobs.Add( $id, $r )

}

# wait for all jobs to complete
while ($False -in $jobs.Values.result.isCompleted) { sleep -Milliseconds 500 }

# print results / close connections. If you see status as RanToCompletion the job is completed successfuly

foreach($j in $jobs.Keys) {
 $res = $jobs[$j].result
[PSCustomObject]@{JobId=$j; isCompleted = $res.isCompleted; Status = $res.Status; result = $res.Result }
$jobs[$j].conn.close()

}
```

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you very much for the reply. Upon trying to execute the above code, I am getting the following error: Method invocation failed because [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand] doesn't contain a method named 'ExecuteNonQueryAsyn
c'.
At line:13 char:34
+    $w = $cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (ExecuteNonQueryAsync:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "Key cannot be null.
Parameter name: key"

Comment: Ah, I guess that's because your ps/.net version is too old. Can you install software on your machine? It's probably a good time to upgrade powershell, or you can try to get powershell core (so it will not interfere with your current ps version). If not then you can modify that script to run single job and using regular sync method (ExecuteNonQuery), then run it as a job with Start-Job

Comment: Hi Mike, I am not sure if I can get the upgrade or PowerShell Core. If I try to use the regular sync method, would it still run all the jobs concurrently? Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: Yes. PS job just execute your script in a separate shell (process). I'll add some samples later. Btw, do you have Invoke-Sqlcmd cmdlet? Typically  you should have it after management studio instllation.

Comment: Sorry Mike, I was on vacation. I've got PowerShell 4.0 installed on my machine now and getting the following error when running the above code.

Comment: Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: '2'  Key being added:
'2'"
At line:4 char:3
+   $jobs.Add( $id, $r )
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException

Comment: That should be because job_id is not unique. You may combine it with code to make it unique (you can do it in sql foreaxmple). Or you can use arraylist instead of hashtable. I used hashtable to keep refernce to job (so you can see which result belong to which job), but this is optional

Comment: Thanks Mike! Sorry, for getting late on this. Unfortunately, we determined to drop the idea of using PS due to some security concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have powershell V2, I'm adding a solution with PS Jobs. Save the code below as sqlExec.ps1:

```
param($connStr, $sql) 

$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $connStr
$cmd = $conn.CreateCommand()
$conn.Open()
$cmd.CommandText = $sql
$r = $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
$conn.Close()
return $r
```

Then use this code as a master script:

```
$str = "Server = YourServer; Database = YourDB; Integrated Security = True;"

$code = "ABC"
$date = (get-date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$execSript = "path\to\sqlExec.ps1"

# get a list of ids for code. You can achive the same with Invoke-sqlcmd or similar cmdlet.
 $conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $str
 $cmd = $conn.CreateCommand()
 $conn.Open()
 $cmd.CommandText = "select job_id, code from test.control_table where code = '$code'"
 $dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable "result"
 $r = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
 $dt.Load($r)
 $conn.Close()

# main loop

$jobs = @{}

foreach($id in $dt.job_id) {  $top = $id*3

  $sql = "EXEC run_job $id, $date"

  $jobs.Add($id,(Start-Job -FilePath $execSript -ArgumentList $str, $sql))

}

# Wait for jobs and get result

$jobs.Values | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

If you have Invoke-Sqlcmd module you can use it for sql code execution (instead of creating $conn,$cmd,etc)